# To publish Sheets Add-on publicly, do I need to have my company domain owner account or can I publish from generic Gmail account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I followed Google's add-on publishing steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish), but it says I need to request for Verification and verify that I own a property. But I do not want to make this generic account as an official owner of my company - we have a separate Admin Google account for our company domain.

[image]

Comment: This is really a question for Google, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Here is a [link to get help from Apps Script Support](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support).